# Odoo 13' solution to solve about the employee forget to checkout in odoo attendance

Tags: python, odoo, time-and-attendance

I would like to ask about the auto checkout in attendance odoo, because employees often forget to check out. Thus, I would like to mark their checkout automatically.

How is the code and where I can insert this code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ":" at the end of the line.

```
records = self.search([('check_out', '=', False), ('check_in', '!=', False)])
```

Comment: I received an error after removing the ":" at the end of the line :     Forbidden opcode(s) in "model.cron_set_attedance_checkout(),\nclass hr_attendace(models.Model):\n\n    _inherit = 'hr.attendance'\n\n    @api.model\n\n    def cron_set_attedance_checkout(self):\n         records = self.search([('check_out', '=', False), ('check_in', '!=', False)])\n\n         for record in records:\n\n            record.check_out = record.check_in": LOAD_BUILD_CLASS

Comment: Thank you for your support. You right!. The code must be remove ":" at the end. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Place this in check in button method.

```
self.expires_in = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

Activate a scheduler whose interval is 1 mint. To check the following lines.

```
expires_in = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(self.expires_in) / 1e3)
expires_in = expires_in + timedelta(seconds=32400) //9 hours seconds
nowDateTime = datetime.now()
if nowDateTime > expires_in:
   checkout_button_method()
```

Let me explain little bit.. The above most line execute a store a check in time. After scheduler is running it will adding 9 hours after its check in. If time is greater than 9 hours it automatically calls the checkout method and perform checkout button duty.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your support. You mean that place your code in Technical --> Automation --> Scheduled Actions ... or where is the check in button method? Please guide more clearly!

Comment: @Khanh listen, First of all make a scheduler which run a method after every 1 minute. In your method which is totally for scheduler place that code. In this method if condition is true it will call the check out button method. SIMPLE. Second thing for that condition you have to safe time in a variable at the time of check in which is 'expires_in' . Because with the help of that filed you will compare checkin time and current time and the IF condition.

Answer (score 0):

In last update You Must Delete comment sarting with //
then save it work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30687150)